# Collect unique elements from array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have this data:

```
   [
      {
         "identifier"=>"A",
         "inclusion"=>"true",
         "name"=>"FGFR2",
         "specific"=>"false"
      },
      0
   ],
   [
      {
         "identifier"=>"A",
         "inclusion"=>true",
         "name"=>"FGFR2",
         "specific"=>"false"
      },
      1
   ],
   [
      {
         "identifier"=>"B",
         "inclusion"=>"true",
         "name"=>"ALK",
         "specific"=>"false"
      },
      {
         "identifier"=>"A",
         "inclusion"=>"true",
         "name"=>"FGFR2",
         "specific"=>"false"
      },
      4
   ],
   [
      {
         "identifier"=>"A",
         "inclusion"=>"true",
         "name"=>"FGFR2",
         "specific"=>"false"
      },
      5
   ]
]
```

I am trying to extract unique elements based on the key 'identifier' reserving the index already stored

I would want the output like this

```
   [
      {
         "identifier"=>"A",
         "inclusion"=>"true",
         "name"=>"FGFR2",
         "specific"=>"false"
      },
      0
   ],
   [
      {
         "identifier"=>"B",
         "inclusion"=>"true",
         "name"=>"ALK",
         "specific"=>"false"
      },
      {
         "identifier"=>"A",
         "inclusion"=>"true",
         "name"=>"FGFR2",
         "specific"=>"false"
      },
      4
   ]
]
```

I tried a couple of ways using map, each_with_index and also map_with_index but they are not working as expected.

Could someone please help me.

Comment: identifier A is return twice in your output. It's not immediately clear why.

Comment: Because if identifier A and B when compared with identifier A makes it unique
thats the reason returning the whole array with identifier A

Comment: the 4th array in the input consists of 2 hashes where as the remaining arrays contains just one element

Comment: Could you elaborate on how "unique" is defined?

Comment: "they are not working as expected" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Comment: I would like to extract unique array elements from the array of hashes based on the identifier value. since the input has multiple identifier A and one single identifier B 
the output should contain A and B identifier elements like in the output above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure it can be greatly improved by the Ruby expert here but here is a code that should do what you want:

- `array` is the name of your intial array of array
- I then create a copy of this `array`, keeping only the Identifier. `array2 = [["A"], ["A"], ["B", "A"], ["A"]]`
- And then I iterate over the `array` and, for each element, check if the first position of this element in `array2` is equal to the current position in `array2`.

```rb
array = [[{"identifier" => "A"...},0]...]

array2 = array.map { |arr| arr.map { |obj| obj.is_a?(Hash) ? obj['identifier'] : nil }.compact }

array.each_with_index.map { |arr, i| array2.index(array2[i]).eql?(i) ? arr : nil }.compact

# [[{"identifier"=>"A", "inclusion"=>"true", "name"=>"FGFR2", "specific"=>"false"}, 0], [{"identifier"=>"B", "inclusion"=>"true", "name"=>"ALK", "specific"=>"false"}, {"identifier"=>"A", "inclusion"=>"true", "name"=>"FGFR2", "specific"=>"false"}, 4]]
```

Comment: This definitely did the job for me. Thank you so very much.